# Stacking Munin graph plugins

Tags: munin

Is there a simple way to stack existing plugin graphs and hide the originals? For example, I'd like to stack `ping_` with say, `ping_google.com` and `ping_amazon.com` together. Do I need to write a new plugin, or can I do it in the config file? And what do I need to look at to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple? Not really.  What you have to do is rewrite the plugins to provide the output you desire and to not make the output you want to hide.  If you look at the existing plugins, you'll get a feel for how the plugins work in terms of data collection and output definitions.  For the most part it is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible.
Check out: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/stack_examples

Comment: I should rephrase my question - I know it's possible, but I'm not sure where to get the graph names from, and I'd like to hide the originals as well.